# Adding fields to a nested document in mongoDB using Node js mongoDB driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I wanted to know how to write a update for mongoDB using the Node js driver with the requirement as below

My document in a collection is as such

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5a4e098e734d1d089c5a7473"
},
"username": "guest",
"password": "guest",
"categories": {
    "movie": [
        "Minions",
    ]
}
}
```

Now i want to add a new field in categories named games with an array as its value for a particular username

i wrote the query as below but it didn't work

```
db.collection('userdata').aggregate([ { '$match': { "username": "guest" } },{ '$addFields ': { "catagories.games" : [] }}],function(err, docs) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log(docs);
```

});

I want to know where am i going wrong or how to solve this issue

Comment: `aggregate` doesn't change the collection. It only reads data from there and transforms it in current cursor.

Answer (score 0):

u can use update feature of mongodb

```
db.userdata.update(
   { "username": "guest" },
   $set:{
      "catagories.games" : []
   },
   { upsert: true }
)
```

upsert true means if not exist,then insert
source-https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: The `upsert` option shouldn't be there; the OP didn't say anything about creating the doc if the username isn't found.

Comment: yes.its Optional. If set to true, creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria. The default value is false.Here guest already exists.